# Strut Framework

Tags: struts

Recently i have completed my first project using strut framework. And i want to run the project in my web space (www.mywebsite.com) instead of running it as http://localhost . How do i run it in my website? Can someone guide me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an application server, if your application only uses Servlet API (you don't have EJB's) I recommend you that install [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) servers. 
Second, you must package your application in a [WAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29); depending on the build tool you are using, it probably offers you some facilites to do that
Third, deploy the WAR file in the application server